# Expiry date mismatch in manual and automatic signing

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xcode10

We are facing the issue as below.

We are able to generate the ipa file (using enterprise account) both manual signing and automatic signing.

Automatic Signing:- After ipa generated, when we are extract the ipa file and open the embedded.mobileprovisional file then we are able to see expiry date as "May 21,2019" , but when we tried the same in

Manual Signing:- when ipa is generated using manual signing then when we extract the ipa file check the expiry date then it "Mar 3, 2019" .

Why there is date difference between manual and automatic signing even for same bundle id.

And the IPA is still working today.and we renewed the manually created provisional certificate and now the validity is May 17 , 2020.

Kindly help us.

Note:- We are using inhouse/Ad-hoc enterprise distribution of ipa file. We are not uploading for App-Store.

Answer (score 0):

Manual signing - you choose the provisioning profile, most likely created manually at the developer portal by some developer sometime earlier.

Automatic signing - Xcode creates and maintains the certificate and provisioning profile, most likely created a new one when the Automatic signing was first enabled and is still using that one.

If you go to the developer portal (developer.apple.com), you'll probably be able to find that you have two distribution certificates, and two different provisioning profiles for the app.

Edit: it seems that automatically generated provisioning profiles do not show under the developer portal list. They still work as well though.

Comment: In the developer portal , I am able see the only one provisional certificate which is manual created. But ideally for same bundle I'd provisional certificate expiry date should be same for both manual and automatically right?

Comment: Well, I just had a look at my developer portal, and neither of my automatic provisioning profiles are there. You don't need to worry though, automatic works just as well as manual.

Comment: Correct we are not able to see the automatically created provisional certificate in portal, but why there is a expiry date difference for manual and automatic any idea?

Comment: Because they were created at different points in time. Your manual certificate was created exactly a year ago, while the profiles were still valid for one year, so it expires tomorrow. Somewhere around October when you enabled the automatic provisioning, the valid duration was changed to two years, so that's why the automatic profile will expire further in the future.

Comment: Edited my question, so expiry date will very for manual and automatic signing? how can we renew the automatically created provisional certificate before expiry date say 2 days before.